# How to use combination in this question

Tags: combinations

In how many ways can n people be divided into 2 equal groups or 3 equal groups (given that n is a factor of 6)

I don't know how to utilize combination to solve this problem, as it is about splitting people into groups instead of finding how many possibilities to form a group.

Can someone explain how to use the combination rule to solve this problem with dividing people into groups?

Comment: 1. Doesn't splitting people into groups amount to the same as forming teams ?  2. Are the groups distinguishable (labelled) or indistinguishable (unlabelled) ?

Comment: They are indistinguishable so combination rather than permutations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To divide a group of n people into two, you pick $\frac{n}{2}$ people from the group. This can be done in $\binom{n}{n/2}$ ways. You can find the number of ways to divide them into 3 groups following the same logic.

Comment: So for groups of 3 it is $\binom{n}{n/3}$ and so on?

Comment: Yes.  It is important that 3 and 2 divide n, otherwise $ \binom {n}{n/2} $ and $ \binom {n}{n/3} $ will be meaningless.